# Setting Format for Query Defined Field

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I have the following query in iSeries SQL which I output to a file.

```
SELECT SSLOTMAK, SSLOTMDL, SSLOTYER, sum(SSCOUNT)       
FROM prqhdrss                                                      
GROUP BY SSLOTMAK, SSLOTMDL, SSLotyer 
HAVING sum(SSCOUNT) > 4 
ORDER BY SSLOTMAK, SSLOTMDL, SSLOTYER
```

When I run it, the field created be the sum(SSCOUNT) is a 31 Packed field. This does not allow me to send it to my PC. How can I force SQL to create the field as a non-packed field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT SSLOTMAK, SSLOTMDL, SSLOTYER, cast(sum(SSCOUNT) as integer)
FROM prqhdrss
GROUP BY SSLOTMAK, SSLOTMDL, SSLotyer
HAVING sum(SSCOUNT) > 4
ORDER BY SSLOTMAK, SSLOTMDL, SSLOTYER
```

I've casted to integer because of the name of the column "count". If the column has floating-point values you can use `numeric(8, 2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to bring it to your PC? Most iSeries methods I know will automatically convert that to a PC-readable format.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that FTP for one will not convert packed data to a  format that's easy to use on the pc side.